# Programming Logic - Splitting up Tasks Between Threads

Tags: math, language-agnostic, programming-languages, multiprocessing

Lets say you want 5 threads to process data simultaneous. Also assume, you have 89 tasks to process.

Off the bat you know 89 / 5 = 17 with a remainder of 4. The best way to split up tasks would be to have  4 (the remainder) threads process 18 (17+1) tasks each and then have 1 (# threads - remainder) thread to process 17.

This will eliminate the remainder. Just to verify:

```
Thread 1: Tasks  1-18  (18 tasks)
Thread 2: Tasks 19-36  (18 tasks)
Thread 3: Tasks 37-54  (18 tasks)
Thread 4: Tasks 55-72  (18 tasks)
Thread 5: Tasks 73-89  (17 tasks)
```

Giving you a total of 89 tasks completed.

I need a way of getting the start and ending range of each thread mathematically/programmability; where the following should print the exact thing I have listed above:

```
$NumTasks = 89
$NumThreads = 5
$Remainder = $NumTasks % $NumThreads 
$DefaultNumTasksAssigned = floor($NumTasks / $NumThreads)

For $i = 1 To $NumThreads
    if $i <= $Remainder Then
        $NumTasksAssigned = $DefaultNumTasksAssigned + 1
    else
        $NumTasksAssigned = $DefaultNumTasksAssigned
    endif
    $Start = ??????????
    $End = ??????????
    print Thread $i: Tasks $Start-$End ($NumTasksAssigned tasks)
Next
```

This should also work for any number of `$NumTasks`.

Note: Please stick to answering the math at hand and avoid suggesting or assuming the situation.

Comment: Why do you want exactly 5 threads to be simultaneously processing?  That seems like a very odd number to just pull out of thin air.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I second Will Hartung 's remark.  You may just feed them one task at a time (or a few tasks at a at a time, depending if there's much overhead, i.e. if individual tasks get typically completed very fast, relative to the cost of starting/recycling threads).*  Your subsequent comments effectively explain that your "threads" carry a heavy creation cost, and hence your desire to feed them once with as much work as possible, rather than wasting time creating new "thread" each fed a small amount of work.

Anyway... going to the `math question`...

If you'd like to assign tasks just once, the following formula, plugged in lieu of the the ?????????  in your logic, should do the trick:

```
$Start = 1 
         + (($i -1) * ($DefaultNumTasksAssigned + 1) 
        - (floor($i / ($Remainder + 1)) * ($i - $Remainder))
$End = $Start + $NumTasksAssigned -1
```

**The formula is explained as follow:**
        1 is for the fact that your display / logic is one-based not zero-based
       The second term is because we generally add ($DefaultNumTasksAssigned + 1) with each iteration.
        The third term provides a correction for the last few iterations.
             Its first part, `(floor($i / ($Remainder + 1))` provides 0 until $i reaches the first thread 
       that doesn't receive one extra task, and 1 thereafter.
       The second part express by how much we need to correct.

The formula for $End is easier, the only trick is the minus 1, it is because the Start and End values are inclusive (so for example between 1 an 19 there are 19 tasks not 18)

The following slightly modified piece of logic should also work, it avoids the "fancy" formula by keeping a running tab of the $Start variable, rather than recomputing it each time..

```
$NumTasks = 89
$NumThreads = 5
$Remainder = $NumTasks % $NumThreads 
$DefaultNumTasksAssigned = floor($NumTasks / $NumThreads)
$Start = 1
For $i = 1 To $NumThreads
    if $i <= $Remainder Then    // fixed here!  need <= because $i is one-based
        $NumTasksAssigned = $DefaultNumTasksAssigned + 1
    else
        $NumTasksAssigned = $DefaultNumTasksAssigned
    endif
    $End = $Start + $NumTasksAssigned -1
    print Thread $i: Tasks $Start-$End ($NumTasksAssigned tasks)

    $Start = $Start + $NumTasksAssigned
Next
```

Here's a Python transcription of the above

```
>>> def ShowWorkAllocation(NumTasks, NumThreads):
...   Remainder = NumTasks % NumThreads
...   DefaultNumTasksAssigned = math.floor(NumTasks / NumThreads)
...   Start = 1
...   for i in range(1, NumThreads + 1):
...     if i <= Remainder:
...        NumTasksAssigned = DefaultNumTasksAssigned + 1
...     else:
...        NumTasksAssigned = DefaultNumTasksAssigned
...     End = Start + NumTasksAssigned - 1
...     print("Thread ", i, ": Tasks ", Start, "-", End, "(", NumTasksAssigned,")")
...     Start = Start + NumTasksAssigned
...
>>>
>>> ShowWorkAllocation(89, 5)
Thread  1 : Tasks  1 - 18 ( 18 )
Thread  2 : Tasks  19 - 36 ( 18 )
Thread  3 : Tasks  37 - 54 ( 18 )
Thread  4 : Tasks  55 - 72 ( 18 )
Thread  5 : Tasks  73 - 89 ( 17 )

>>> ShowWorkAllocation(11, 5)
Thread  1 : Tasks  1 - 3 ( 3 )
Thread  2 : Tasks  4 - 5 ( 2 )
Thread  3 : Tasks  6 - 7 ( 2 )
Thread  4 : Tasks  8 - 9 ( 2 )
Thread  5 : Tasks  10 - 11 ( 2 )
>>>

>>> ShowWorkAllocation(89, 11)
Thread  1 : Tasks  1 - 9 ( 9 )
Thread  2 : Tasks  10 - 17 ( 8 )
Thread  3 : Tasks  18 - 25 ( 8 )
Thread  4 : Tasks  26 - 33 ( 8 )
Thread  5 : Tasks  34 - 41 ( 8 )
Thread  6 : Tasks  42 - 49 ( 8 )
Thread  7 : Tasks  50 - 57 ( 8 )
Thread  8 : Tasks  58 - 65 ( 8 )
Thread  9 : Tasks  66 - 73 ( 8 )
Thread  10 : Tasks  74 - 81 ( 8 )
Thread  11 : Tasks  82 - 89 ( 8 )
>>>
```

Comment: You forgot to keep `$NumTasksAssigned` -- because of this your output is not right on. `$Start = $Start + $DefaultNumTasksAssigned` should be `$Start = $Start + $NumTasksAssigned`. This will make it fit the example, but if I change `$NumTasks=11` it fails.

Comment: @BHare.  You're right, it is useful to keep $NumTasksAssigned. See my after dinner edits (I code better on a full stomach)... I had assumed I could get rid of because on the _last_ "thread" would not get the max amount of task assigned but that was of course just an impression given by the particular 89 value.  88 for eg. will have two "threads" with one less task. etc.

Comment: This example yields task 89 never going into effect. Output is here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=avT3MD8m -- Anyways, moot point because I achieved success using your original as a base. A working model is here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=He86vE97  -- meta math answer made it simpler: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46014/programming-logic-splitting-up-tasks-between-threads ... Please update your answer accordingly if you wish to get accepted. Otherwise ill have mods close it out.

Comment: @BHare  Oops/LOL, we can never take these "simple ones" for granted...  The mistake in my snippet is that he test on `i < $Remainder` should be  `i <= $Remainder` [edited accordingly].  I like the math.stackexchange solution as well.

Comment: Almost there. The `NumTasksAssigned` and the amount of Threads that take care of the Remainder is fixed, but job 72 is processed twice (once by Thread 4, and again as Thread 5). Effectively still skipping 89. Output here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=2ireihwF . If we set `$NumTasks=11` then output is even worse: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=hrBXHL7F

Comment: @BHAre, do check again the logic on your end. Unless I missed the obvious the Python snippet I added to response is an exact transcription of the PHP-looking code (which I can't test ATM),  and it produces the desired output, properly handling task # 72 etc.

Comment: You are right, I was still using `$Start = 1 + (($i -1) * ($DefaultNumTasksAssigned + 1) - (floor($i / ($Remainder + 1)) * ($i - $Remainder)))` which doesnt seem to been updated from your `<` to `<=` update. Using the other code works as expected. Accepted solution.

Answer (score 7):

Why? Rather then predetermining the scheduling order, stick all of the tasks on a queue, and then have each thread pull them off one by one when they're ready. Then your tasks will basically run "as fast as possible".

If you pre-allocated, then one thread may be doing a particularly long bit of processing and blocking the running of all the tasks stuck behind it. Using the queue, as each task finishes and a thread frees up, it grabs the next task and keeps going.

Think of it like a bank with 1 line per teller vs one line and a lot of tellers. In the former, you might get stuck behind the person depositing coins and counting it out one by one, the latter you get to the next available teller, while Mr. PocketChange counts away.

Comment: The language I am working with actually doesn't support true multithreading, but rather parallel processing. The idea here is to "keep-alive" the process for as long as possible because "freeing" one means a process is closed and another one is open, which takes more time than the processing itself. My method is to have 5 concurrent processes running for most of the time, each working on their own little tasks simultaneously.

Comment: @BHare: Then why did you tag this question `c#` and `php`?

Comment: That's fine, but if you have shared access to resources, there's no difference between using the shared queue as a source of tasks and the pre-allocated list. The queue will add some synchronization of some kind, of course (but that may well not be a problem depending on your multi-tasking).

Comment: No shared access to resources, the "parallel processing" is really a unsupported hack to get it to work. I could use inter-process communication but that's a bit over the top for the problem. This will simply send the process its instructions (process tasks x - y) and from that point on it will only get its output, it cant interact.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've [solved the wrong half of your problem](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060323-00/?p=31803).

It's going to be virtually impossible to precisely determine the time it will take to complete all your tasks, unless all of the following are true:

- your tasks are 100% CPU-bound: that is, they use 100% CPU while running and don't need to do any I/O
- none of your tasks have to synchronize with any of your other tasks in any way
- you have exactly as many threads as you have CPUs
- the computer that is running these tasks is not performing any other interesting tasks at the same time

In practice, most of the time, your tasks are I/O-bound rather than CPU-bound: that is, you are waiting for some external resource such as reading from a file, fetching from a database, or communicating with a remote computer.  In that case, you only make things worse by adding more threads, because they're all contending for the same scarce resource.

Finally, unless you have some really weird hardware, it's unlikely you can actually have exactly five threads running simultaneously.  (Usually processor configurations come in multiples of at least two.)  Usually the sweet spot is at about 1 thread per CPU if your tasks are very CPU-bound, about 2 threads per CPU if the tasks spend half their time being CPU-bound and half their time doing IO, etc.

**tl;dr**: We need to know a lot more about what your tasks and hardware look like before we can advise you on this question.

Comment: They aren't really threads, but rather processes. Each process will be processing a winhttp GET or POST request (no support for asynchronous requests in the language) . I chose 5 because it seems to be the quickest in testing.

Comment: @BHare: That doesn't invalidate anything I wrote.  If previous testing found 5 threads to be fastest, that implies that there's probably a roughly 80%-20% split between CPU activity and I/O activity, and that it's either (1) the CPU work that's taking 80% of the time and you're on a quad-core machine, or (2) it's the I/O that's taking 80%-100% of the time, but you can effectively interleave four requests at a time.  I have a hunch that (2) is your bottleneck because you mention that you're doing HTTP, and browsers typically only make 4 requests at a time to a single server.